# Calling specific keys from within JSON hierarchy

Tags: php, objective-c, json

I have a hierarchy of users that I need to access within an app, each with their own specific information. I'm not sure how to utilize **objectForKey** to call a specific user's key, and how to then pull specific pieces of information from each of the keys within each user's hierarchy.

Here's my PHP:

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$arr = array(
    '0' =>
        array(
            'userName'=>'user1',
            'userBio'=>'This is user1 bio.',
            'userSubmitted'=>'15'
        ),
    '1' =>
        array(
            'userName'=>'user2',
            'userBio'=>'This is user2 bio.',
            'userSubmitted'=>'2'
        ),
    '2' =>
        array(
            'userName'=>'user3',
            'userBio'=>'This is user3 bio.',
            'userSubmitted'=>'7'
        ),
);

echo json_encode($arr);


?>
```

Here's my Objective C:

```
    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://domain.com/json2.php"];
    NSData *myData1 = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
    NSError *error1;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error1];


    if(!error1)
    {
        for (id user in jsonDict1)
        {
            [user objectForKey: @"userName"];
            textUser.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [user objectForKey: @"userName"]];

            [user objectForKey: @"userBio"];
            textBio.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [user objectForKey: @"userBio"]];

            [user objectForKey: @"userSubmitted"];
            textSubmitted.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [user objectForKey: @"userSubmitted"]];
        }
    }

    else{

        [jsonDict1 objectForKey: @"userName"];
        textUser.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error--%@",[error1 description]];
    }

}
```

Additionally, this code is successful when compiled. However, I don't have a choice of which user's information is displayed. Therein lies my issue.

Comment: Add an `NSLog( @"%@", jsonDict1 );` after the `NSJSONSerialization` line, and post the results.  I'm not convinced the PHP generates the format you expect.

Comment: 2014-03-26 18:11:44.392 testtest[3263:60b] (
        {
        userBio = "This is user1 bio.";
        userName = user1;
        userSubmitted = 15;
    },
        {
        userBio = "This is user2 bio.";
        userName = user2;
        userSubmitted = 2;
    },
        {
        userBio = "This is user3 bio.";
        userName = user3;
        userSubmitted = 7;
    }
)

Comment: @user3386109 My NSLog can be found above. Not sure if you could help me figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: So basically you have an NSArray of NSDictionary.  How you retrieve information from that dataset depends on what you want to do.  One possibility is that you have a UITableView to display the data.  The other possibility is just to use the json data like a database, and do queries on it.  Which of those are you trying to do?

Comment: @user3386109 I am working towards using this system as one that will auto populate a feed with information provided by users. Right now I'm testing it by populating 3 different users from pre-filled json file (not yet connected to the database...we're more than a few steps away). I personally don't believe that a UITableView is the way I'd like to go...unless it can be heavily styled in such a way that it looks...well, nothing like a UITableView.

Comment: I posted an answer.  If you run the code, the output from the NSLog should be `This is user2 bio.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSJSONSerialization` would produce an `NSMutableArray` for your case. And you should avoid performing `objectForKey:` method on your `jsonDict1` object.

Also you don't have to format your strings with `stringWithFormat:@"%@"`. Actually you shouldn't do. Because if the string is null, then your label would contain `(null)`. But it would seem entry in below implementation.

That implementation could be like this:

```
NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://domain.com/json2.php"];
NSData *myData1 = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
NSError *error1;
NSArray *users = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error1];


if(!error1)
{
    for (NSDictionary * user in users)
    {
        textUser.text = [user objectForKey: @"userName"];

        textBio.text = [user objectForKey: @"userBio"];

        textSubmitted.text = [user objectForKey: @"userSubmitted"];
    }
}

else
{
    textUser.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error--%@",[error1 description]];
}
```

And you better use your PHP code like below. So you can be sure it is an array, and process `userSubmitted` field as an `NSNumber` instead of `NSString`.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$arr = array(
    0 =>
        array(
            'userName'=>'user1',
            'userBio'=>'This is user1 bio.',
            'userSubmitted'=>15
        ),
    1 =>
        array(
            'userName'=>'user2',
            'userBio'=>'This is user2 bio.',
            'userSubmitted'=>2
        ),
    2 =>
        array(
            'userName'=>'user3',
            'userBio'=>'This is user3 bio.',
            'userSubmitted'=>7
        ),
);

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

I am not concerning about your implementation details. You are setting text for your views in a loop. It does not make sense because only the last object would be written into them.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough response! This threw an error around

            textSubmitted.text = [user objectForKey: @"userSubmitted"];

This is what the debug area says, "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]:"

Also, your final comment about printing the last piece of data is actually what I'm experiencing. This is the first in a few steps towards pulling from a database and printing all sets of information given into a feed. How else might I set this up to move towards that goal?

Comment: You should give an `NSString` to your view `textSubmitted` if it is a kind of `UILabel`. You can use `[[user objectForKey: @"userSubmitted"] description]` to produce string from your `NSNumber` object.

Comment: Sorry, it is my fault in the `textSubmitted` situation, i forgot that. If i understand correctly, you wanna show all users in a structure. If it is right, you can use a table view for your goal. You can look at the documentation about `UITableView`, or `UITableViewController` for simpler implementation.

Comment: While I do greatly appreciate your answer and your help in cleaning up the code, I'm afraid my question stands. How might I call specific key values from deep within the hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

The following code demonstrates how to do queries on an NSArray of NSDictionary's, treating said data as though it were contained in a database.  (Normally, the jsonResult is downloaded from a server, but for demonstration purposes, the jsonResult is initialized statically in the code.) For more information on using predicates, see this [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789), and especially the section on the [predicate format string syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB)

```
- (void)test
{
    NSArray *jsonResult = @[
      @{ @"userBio" : @"This is user1 bio.", @"userName" : @"user1", @"userSubmitted" : @"15" },
      @{ @"userBio" : @"This is user2 bio.", @"userName" : @"user2", @"userSubmitted" : @"2"  },
      @{ @"userBio" : @"This is user3 bio.", @"userName" : @"user3", @"userSubmitted" : @"7"  }
    ];

    NSString *bio = [self retrieveUserBioFromData:jsonResult ForUser:@"user2"];
    NSLog( @"%@", bio );
}

- (NSString *)retrieveUserBioFromData:(NSArray *)dataArray ForUser:(NSString *)userName
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userName == %@", userName];

    // the filtered array should have only one entry for the given userName
    NSArray *filtered = [dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    if ( filtered.count >= 1 )
    {
        NSDictionary *userinfo = filtered[0];
        return( userinfo[@"userBio"] );
    }
    else
    {
        return( nil );      // didn't find the requested userName
    }
}
```